# Sort-Object problem (one MAC address and two IP addresses)

Tags: powershell

I have as `input.csv` file and in inside is for example:

```
MAC: 00-1A-4B-2E-FF-04  IP: 10.3.100.62
MAC: 00-1A-4B-2E-FF-04  IP: 10.14.21.11

MAC: 00-1B-78-15-FE-58  IP: 10.14.6.24
MAC: 00-1B-78-15-FE-58  IP: 10.3.128.57

MAC: 00-01-E6-35-68-88  IP: 10.14.23.15
MAC: 00-1B-78-21-AC-36  IP: 10.3.88.59
```

I need using `Sort-Object MAC -Unique` but in `output.csv` want:

```
MAC: 00-1A-4B-2E-FF-04                10.14.21.11
MAC: 00-1B-78-15-FE-58                10.14.6.24

00-01-E6-35-68-88       IP: 10.14.23.15
00-1B-78-21-AC-36       IP: 10.3.88.59
```

Simple if there are two IP addresses for one MAC addrees I need always only one unique combination, but always the IP address that starts with `10.14.*.*`.

I try this:

```
$getFile = Get-Content $file |
           ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Header "Tiskarna", "Model", "MAC", "IP_adresa", "ID_terminalu" |
           Sort-Object -Property MAC, IP_adresa |
           ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
           % {$_.Replace('"','')} |
           Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

Comment: [1] your delimiter does not match the sample data [semi-colon in code, space in sample data]. [2] your header does not match your sample data [5 columns in code, 4 in sample].

Comment: please take a look on image you can understand what i want. this code work. Problem is that Sort-Object -Property MAC - Uniq delete duplicity randomly but i need delete MAC adrees duplicity according IP adress

Comment: Does your file _actually_ look like that? ie. if you open it in notepad or similar, it actually says "MAC:" in front of each mac address?

Comment: @PatrikŽivčak - that is NOT a CSV file. [*grin*] what are your headers supposed to go with? where is the semi-colon delimiter that your code mentions?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen as the image only repeats the (reformatted) text, I didn't embed it intentionally. Both don't seem to represent the real csv file.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your input data doesn't look like an actual CSV. Please open the file in an editor, then [edit] your question and copy/paste a sample from that file into your question.

Comment: My code is here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/Qq8EQYyW

Comment: My code is here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/Qq8EQYyW he works and  this is output this code in excel is here: https://ibb.co/P5FjkbL I need now sort this duplicity mac adress where ip is 10.14.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your preferred IPs starting with `10.14.` will ***always*** be sorted first, use `Group-Object` :

```bsh
# simulating Import-Csv input.csv  
$Csv = @"
00-1A-4B-2E-FF-04;10.3.100.62
00-1A-4B-2E-FF-04;10.14.21.11
00-1B-78-15-FE-58;10.14.6.24
00-1B-78-15-FE-58;10.3.128.57
00-01-E6-35-68-88;10.14.23.15
00-1B-78-21-AC-36;10.3.88.59
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header MAC,IP

$Output = $Csv | Group-Object Mac | ForEach { 
  $_.Group | Sort-Object IP | Select-Object -First 1 
}

$Output
```

yields here:

```
MAC               IP
---               --
00-1A-4B-2E-FF-04 10.14.21.11
00-1B-78-15-FE-58 10.14.6.24
00-01-E6-35-68-88 10.14.23.15
00-1B-78-21-AC-36 10.3.88.59
```